# Android - default button style

Tags: java, android, button, styles

**Question:**
Where can I find default styles xml with hexadecimal codes of colors?

I'm looking for Style 'buttonStyle' and other default styles witch affect aspects like TextViews, Buttons etc (if you dont change the style of aspect)

I looked up in `<instalation_folder>\android-sdk\platforms\android-<versio>\data\res\values` and `<instalation_folder>\android-sdk\platforms\android-<version>\data\res\colors` but I didn't actually find what I was looking for.

Hope my question is clear.

---

Due to low reputation I cant answer this question yet. Here is answer

**Answer**

With a bit of googling I found 'buttonStyle' is actually 'Widget.Button' - 
[Styling Android With Defaults](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/01/styling-android-with-defaults/)

This is how it works:

- As I said 'buttonStyle' style is accualy 'Widget.Button' style defined in `\android-sdk\platforms\android-<version>\data\res\values\styles.xml`. Background is set to: `@android:drawable/btn_default`
- `\android-sdk\platforms\android-<version>\data\res\drawable\btn_default.xml` defines background color of button as selector. Color actually depends on button's state. Default color is set to `@drawable/btn_default_normal`
- With a bit of searching I found, that btn_default_normal is png image located in `\android-sdk\platforms\android-<version>\data\res\drawable-mdpi`

I find it a bit confusing, but I hope it will help someone, maybe...

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Understanding how Android styles do work can be a little bit messy.

I will try to explain how the basic work flow would be, based on an example.

Let's assume you want to know what the default background for buttons is.
This can be either a simple color (unlikely) or a drawable (there are many different types of drawables).

Android has Themes. A theme basically defines which style is applied to which widget.
Therefore, our first step is to find the default android theme.

You find it under `android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\values\themes.xml`

In this theme file, search for `button`.

You will find something like this:

```
<!-- Button styles -->

<item name="buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
```

This means that the theme applies the style `Widget.Button` to buttons.

Ok, now let's find the style `Widget.Button`.

All default Android style are defined in the file `android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\values\styles.xml`

Now search for `Widget.Button`

You will find something like this:

```
<style name="Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

The interesting line is:

`<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>`

This means that there is a drawable called `btn_default` set as button background.

Now we need to find a file named `btn_default.*` in one of the drawable folders under `android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res`.

This can be either an image (very unlikely) or a xml file like `btn_default.xml`.

After a little bit searching you will find the file `android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\drawable\btn_default.xml`

It contains something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
</selector>
```

Now you have to understand that this is a selector drawable (one of the many drawable types).
This selector chooses different backgrounds, based on the buttons state. For example, if the buttons is pressed, it has a different background.

No let's look at the default state.

`<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />`

It applies a drawable called `btn_default_normal`.

Now we need to find this drawable.

Again, we need to find a file named `btn_default_normal.*` in one of the drawable folders under `android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res`.

This can be again either an image or a xml file like `btn_default_normal.xml`.

You will find multiple files called 'btn_default_normal.9.png' in different drawable folders for different resolutions.

:) Now you know that `btn_default_normal.9.png` is set as button background.

Comment: great explained, but how do you search `Widget.Button` and know that it's in this file path under android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\values\styles.xml

Comment: The current Android Studio default projects have `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'` in their `build.gradle` and somehow that changes how the widgets look.

Answer (score 9):

You can find default styles of android widgets when you declare in XML:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Button" - standard Button
style="@android:style/Widget.TextView" - standard TextView
```

For example this is style of default button:

```xml
    <style name="Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

background of default button:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable"/>
</selector>
```

You can get the default color with the help of any graphics editor:
path to default button [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html)
..\android-sdk\platforms\android-13\data\res\drawable-hdpi

Comment: how to do this for Appcompat lib? android:Widget.Button to @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button be nor working!!