# Why doesn't setEnabled(false) trigger a ColorStateList for theme Theme.AppCompat.Light?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I am trying to use `setEnabled(false)` on a `Button` to show grey disabled state...

- I can only get the desired result if I force a theme on the button with

  ```
  android:theme="@style/Button"
  ```

  and then change the parent on that Button style to something other than the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, such as from Material:

  ```
  <style name="Button" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
  ```

  (even then, only the button background changes, the text color doesn't.)
- I **can't** see the Button as grey when set disabled if I leave the Button to take the defaults.  (My understanding is that when using `Theme.AppCompat.`,  `Button` becomes `AppCompat.Widget.Button` and inherits a `ColorStateList`.)

#### In my `res\values\styles.xml`

```
    <resources>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>        
        <!-- only way I could get this to work -->
        <style name="Button" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/butt</item>-->
            <!--<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/butt</item>-->
        </style>        
        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>        
        <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </resources>
```

#### In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    ( and nothing under <activity> )
```

#### My `MainActivity` extends `Activity`

- but I have also tried extends `AppCompatActivity` and had the same problem.

#### So what is going on here?  Why doesn't the default work for a "disabled button"?

- (And *if I do inherit* from `Material` theme (as above), why does the Button text color not change?  Basically, why don't the Buttons look like they do in the theme editor?)

#### Also

- when I specify a custom `ColorStateList` via `res\color`, why can't I override just some of the states?  I tried to have only

  ```
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#616161" />
  ```

  But it didn't work.  I was only able to get a greyed disable Button using this method if I specified more `<item>`s, even though I don't care to match other states.  It only works If I add something like:

  ```
  <!-- disabled state -->
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#616161" />    
  <!-- enabled state -->
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLighter" />    
  <!-- default -->
  <item android:color="#ffffff"/>
  ```

#### My `supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'`

I have already seen

[How to setup disabled color of button with AppCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810614/how-to-setup-disabled-color-of-button-with-appcompat)

[Widget.AppCompat.Button colorButtonNormal shows gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860906/widget-appcompat-button-colorbuttonnormal-shows-gray)

[State list drawable and disabled state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042866/state-list-drawable-and-disabled-state)

[Android - default button style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222858/android-default-button-style)

[Android: change color of disabled text using Theme/Style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769198/android-change-color-of-disabled-text-using-theme-style)

[When should one use Theme.AppCompat vs ThemeOverlay.AppCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238433/when-should-one-use-theme-appcompat-vs-themeoverlay-appcompat)

[Use android:theme and ThemeOverlay to theme specific Views and their descendents
Pro-tip by +Ian Lake](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH)

and
[Nesting Android Themes](https://medium.com/@pablisco/nesting-android-themes-8147e0a0d6c8)

I don't want to override the defaults if I don't have to and specify anything I don't have to.   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let me go into more detail to hopefully help clear up some of your questions:

### Activating default material buttons:

*Side note: Overall I think it leads to a more consistent look and behaviour when using the AppCompat Theme to also use `AppCompatActivity` etc.*

But as you noticed just by using the `AppCompat` Theme, a `Button` (Internally mapped to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`) doesn't automatically apply the compatibility material style.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but I suspect it's to keep the look backwards compatible. You can easily activate it by applying the correct style directly on the view:

```
<Button
   style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
   ... />
```

Here is a screenshot to show the different look of enabled and disabled buttons. 
The styled buttons are the first two. The active one has the pink accent color as background. 
The old Android button are the bottom two. As you can see disable only changes the text color and slightly the outline.

[image: Buttons in different styles]

If you want this applied to any button you use in your app, you can add the following line to your `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>
   ...
```

This will use your default colorAccent as button highlight color and a grey tone as a flat disabled button. You mentioned only defining the `android:theme` for your `App` in your Manifest. For this solution to work you might need to set the theme to each `Activity`.

## Defining a color with different states

The idea of the `ColorStateList` is to define a color that changes depending on the state of a `View`. It needs the default case as a fallback in case the conditions of the specific definitions don't match.

Your example can be simplified to the following:

```
<!-- disabled state -->
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#616161" />
<!-- default = enabled state -->
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLighter"/>
```

For buttons you can also make use of the default **disabled alpha** attribute e.g. define `button_accent_stated` =

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:alpha="?android:attr/disabledAlpha"
          android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

## Custom color styling

*If you are happy with the defaults, then you can ignore the following part...*

If you want to style a button (and same for other components) and give it custom colors you need to make the **difference between applying styles and themes**. Both are defined in the `styles.xml` so this can be confusing. I can recommend giving the definitions names that represent how they are used.

When you want to overwrite for example the accent color, you create a **custom `ButtonTheme`** and apply it with `android:theme` as shown in your question.

When you want to adjust the look of a component (e.g. with the material buttons to get a different disabled color), you create a **custom `ButtonStyle`** and apply it with `style`. These definitions need a `parent` that corresponds to the `View`.

With material buttons and latest support libraries the previous approach to set the disabled color with `colorButtonNormal` seems to not work anymore. Instead you can use the color defined in the previous step by creating a custom style and set it as `backgroundTint`.

```
<style name="AppTheme.ButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/button_accent_stated</item>
</style>
```

This will lead to a disabled button like this:
[image: Disabled with alpha accent color]

Again you can apply this style as above per button or overall in your `AppTheme`. If you still need to support pre-lollipop devices you probably will also need a custom theme to set the `colorButtonNormal`.

## Update: Default Material + stated text color:

Played with my example app and the only other explanation I found to what prevents the default stated text color is defining `android:textColorPrimary` on your `AppTheme`!

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryTextOnLight</item>
```

If you have this all buttons without a custom text color will use this text for both states! See [Screenshot](https://github.com/friederikewild/demoStyleAndThemes/raw/master/screenshots/buttons_primary_set.png).

If you just want to fix the button text to change color, you can define your button style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextStatedButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_stated</item>
</style>
```

With `button_text_stated` a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:alpha="?android:disabledAlpha"
          android:color="@color/colorPrimaryTextOnLight" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryTextOnDark" />
</selector>
```

And simply apply this `buttonStyle` for all buttons or as `style` per button as shown above.

I've uploaded my [demo project](https://github.com/friederikewild/demoStyleAndThemes) with more screenshots / combinations of setting styles and themes to Github since I felt this answer was getting too long and it's better to just play with it to understand how styles work.

## Preview in Android studio

As mentioned in the comments I can confirm that the Preview in Android studio is sometimes showing elements wrong, especially when applying a custom theme to an element! Better to test in the emulator or on a real device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am still having the same problem though. To clarify I'm not trying to color the buttons, just want to do `setEnabled(false)` to cause "greyed" background and text colors for that state such as in the lower half of your screenshot.  As mentioned above, I have achieved background-color change by styling buttons with `android:theme="@style/Button` and then `<style name="Button" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">` but the **text color** does not change.  Using `ColorStateList` as suggested does not help that.

Comment: Can you explain further about these points: (1) "by using the AppCompat Theme, a Button (Internally mapped to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`) doesn't automatically apply the compatibility material style",  and (2)  "For this solution to work you might need to set the theme to each Activity." - Why? ... if it is inherited from `<Application>` of manifest.

Comment: To summarize, I am trying to use the defaults wherever possible (and change as little as possible) to achieve the "disabled button appearance",  while also noting that my `MainActivity` extends `Activity` and not `AppCompat...`

Comment: To summarize what I have tried: (as mentioned,) if I use  a style on my `Button` with `parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"` then the disabled appearance is mostly acceptable, but the **text color** does not change... But if I add `<item name>` to this style (for `colorAccent`, `colorButtonNormal` and `android:backgroundTint` which point to a `ColorStateList` using the states you provided) then the background color changes, but the appearance is _actually worse!_  The buttons are now colored, but background-color is wrong for state `enabled false` and again text not changed at all

Comment: Also... to add, I notice the **text color** does not match the `preview pane` in Android Studio _globally_.  So I have defined some `TextView` with `textAppearanceMedium` and this shows as a sort of grey text color in the `preview pane` but does not render the same in a test on a device.  I think my `<styles>` must have a (inheritance?)  problem for sure...

Comment: @TT-- Sorry to hear you still had trouble. In the future, consider updating your question. You could add a new section "UPDATE:" and include new code you tried and open questions. Many comments and open questions are otherwise hard to follow up on. I've played with my demo app and found one possible solution. Updated my answer.
Maybe it helps you downloading my test project and play with styles on there to find the setup you need. I don't want to take more time to change to just Activity, but hope the last suggestion helps with that old class too. Good luck!

Comment: "With material buttons and latest support libraries the previous approach to set the disabled color with colorButtonNormal seems to not work anymore. " --> thank you so much for that, I thought I was going crazy when it wasn't working!