# Setting default background of ImageButton to transparent (using AndroidX)

Tags: android, android-styles, androidx, android-imagebutton

I'm using the AndroidX support libraries. In my manifest I declare:

```
<application
        ...            

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

In `values.styles.xml` I declare:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/MyImageButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyImageButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then I use the ImageButton via:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

Unfortunately, my `ImageButton` shows a grey background instead of the transparent one. What do I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace this line

```
<item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/MyImageButton</item>
```

**with**

```
<item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/MyImageButton</item>
```

And This is also another way given by @[prince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56682006/2196176)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your code to

```
style="@style/MyImageButton"
```

So,

```
<ImageButton
    style="@style/MyImageButton"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

or you don't want to add style in your all button tag you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13223330/4395804) to change the style of the default button. Hope it will help you. Try and let me know it works or not.

Thanks.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `background` of `ImageButton` to `null` as below :

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@null" />
```

This will make your `ImageButton` transparent.

Comment: This question is about getting rid of the work of doing that for every ImageButton via styles. Your answer doesn't use styles or otherwise sets the default.